# How to load web view and image view conditional in collection view with in same section with flexible height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am loading web view and image view on basis of condition. i am unable to manage height for collection view.

Comment: Hey Rajat, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be very helpful if you can share some code snippet and explain your problem through that code. It's difficult to imagine the exact problem without taking a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please write some code, so we could help you better.
Also check this method it could help you:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    //You can set a condition here to check if the collection has an imageView or web view and set the size you want according to it.
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```